# Regular expression to extract all the word after a specific symbol in a word using python

Tags: python, regex

I have to extract all the words of a line just after a word containing special character(^). From the following lines:

```
skipping root#14^wvoice as file not exists

node wroot#15^GetBuildType already complete
```

Expected output:

```
as file does not exists
already complete
```

I tried with regular expression as follows:

```
(?<=\^\w).*
```

But getting the output as:

```
wvoice as file not exists
GetBuildType already complete
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\^\S*\s*(.*)', s)
```

or, to get the first match only:

```
m = re.search(r'\^\S*\s*(.*)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKLmOV/1).

**Details**

- `\^` - a literal `^` is matched
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - then 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than a newline (LF).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oBiCR6):

```
import re
texts=['skipping root#14^wvoice as file not exists','node wroot#15^GetBuildType already complete']
for text in texts:
    m=re.search(r'\^\S*\s*(.*)', text)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
as file not exists
already complete
```

Comment: This is giving output: ^wvoice as file not exists     but I want only  as file not exists

Comment: It does output your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I can give u that

```
\^\w+\s(.*)
```

and then use the second group that match (index = 1)

here is the explanation : [link](https://regex101.com/r/YNQYUa/1/)